# How can I do :clearjumps in ideavim in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I want to clear the jump history by doing :clearjumps, however
ideavim errors out. How can I achieve this in ideavim in Intellij or Pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:clearjumps` is not supported by IdeaVim 0.50. Feel free to file a feature request to the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).